# Copying worksheets from one file to another using VBA macro

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA and just to want create a macro  that copies a worksheet (or sheets) from one file to another file using a simple vba macro each period.

Im sure its easy but as I say, I am new to this world!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please share the code, which you have tried till now. Possibly this might be duplicate. Please search this forum. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have not used code yet - as I say complete novice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (You are lucky that i had a template for this :)) Cheers

Below is the code:

```
Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("B.xlsx")
Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets("Roll Out Summary")
Set sht2 = wkb2.Sheets("Roll Out Summary")

sht1.Cells.Copy
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wkb2.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

For just range:

```
Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets("Roll Out Summary").Range("A1:B10") ' Define the range
Set sht2 = wkb2.Sheets("Roll Out Summary")

sht1.Cells.Copy
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wkb2.Close True
```

Comment: Hi, yes. One thing, if I only wanted to select a range from the source file what other code would I require?